forecast() from MSBVAR throws the following error after executing gibbs. msbvar()
I am trying to fit Indian gdp data using MSBVAR. The code I used is given below. It runs fine with msbvar() function for mode-finder and gibb.s MSBVAR for gibbs sampling, but the forecast() function throws the following error:
m2 <- msbvar(growth_ts, p =1, h = 2, lambda0 = 0.8, lambda1 = 0.15, lambda3 = 1, 
         lambda4 = 0.25, lambda5 = 1, mu5 = 2, mu6 = 2, qm = 4, alpha.prior = 100*2 +      matrix(12, 2, 2), prior = 0, max.iter = 30, initialize.opt = NULL)

#forecasts
m2.gibbs <- gibbs.msbvar(m2, N1 = 1000, N2 = 10000, permute = FALSE, Sigma.idx = 1)
m2.gibbs


m2_forecast <- forecast(m2.gibbs, nsteps = 3, N1 = 1000, N2 = 10000)

Error in matrix(unlist(lapply(x$ss.sample, as.integer)), nrow = TTh, ncol = N) : 
non-numeric matrix extent

I tried to see what unlist(lapply(m2.gibbs$ss.sample, as.integer)) returns. It generates a 10000 sequences of 27 0s and 1s. I do not know how to interpret this result.
I tried to use the code given in the CRAN reference manual for MSBVAR under forecast() function on page 12/92. It is given as:
#checking for gibbs.msbvar and forecast

data(IsraelPalestineConflict)
set.seed(123)
Y.sample1 <- window(IsraelPalestineConflict, end=c(2002, 52))
Y.sample2 <- window(IsraelPalestineConflict, start=c(2003,1))

# MSBVAR forecasts
# Fit model
m1 <- msbvar(Y.sample1, p=1, h=2, lambda0=0.8, lambda1=0.2,
         lambda3=1, lambda4=0.2, lambda5=0, mu5=0, mu6=0,
         qm=12, prior=0)
# Gibbs sampling
m1id <- gibbs.msbvar(m1, N1=1000, N2=10000, permute=FALSE, Sigma.idx=1)
# Forecast density estimation
msforc <- forecast(m1id, nsteps=nrow(Y.sample2), N1=1000, N2=10000)
# Summarize forecasts
apply(msforc$forecasts, c(2,3), mean)

it throws the same error as my code. I do not know what to do and I'm chasing a masters thesis deadline. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
error:
> msforc <- forecast(m1id, nsteps=nrow(Y.sample2), N1=1000, N2=10000)
Error in matrix(unlist(lapply(x$ss.sample, as.integer)), nrow = TTh, ncol = N) : 
non-numeric matrix extent


It's a long shot, but worth checking the version in this answer in case it helps given the original package hasn't been updated for quite a few years.

I have tried that. It helped run a few more functions, but this issue persists.
